# Magento 2 :Admin Grid

Tags: magento2, grid

In my custom module, I want two grids in admin side.I have added the follwing code in di.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * @author Cartin24 Team
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2016 Vendor (http://www.cartin24.com)
 * @package Vendor_Company
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <virtualType name="CompanyGridFilterPool" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\FilterPool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="appliers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="regular" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\RegularFilter</item>
                <item name="fulltext" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\FulltextFilter</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>

    <virtualType name="CompanyGridDataProvider" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collection" xsi:type="object" shared="false">Vendor\Company\Model\ResourceModel\Company</argument>
            <argument name="filterPool" xsi:type="object" shared="false">CompanyGridFilterPool</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>

    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="respbannerslider_data_source" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Company\Model\ResourceModel\Company\Grid\Collection</item>
            </argument>
       </arguments>
    </type>
    <type name="Vendor\Company\Model\ResourceModel\Company\Grid\Collection">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">cartin24_respslidemaster</argument>
            <argument name="eventPrefix" xsi:type="string">respbannerslider_collection</argument>
            <argument name="eventObject" xsi:type="string">respbannerslider_collection</argument>
            <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Company\Model\ResourceModel\Company</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>



    <virtualType name="SlideGridFilterPool" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\FilterPool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="appliers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="regular" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\RegularFilter</item>
                <item name="fulltext" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\FulltextFilter</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>


    <virtualType name="SlideGridDataProvider" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collection" xsi:type="object" shared="false">Vendor\Company\Model\ResourceModel\Slide</argument>
            <argument name="filterPool" xsi:type="object" shared="false">SlideGridFilterPool</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="slide_data_source" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Company\Model\ResourceModel\Slide\Grid\Collection</item>
            </argument>
       </arguments>
    </type>


   <type name="Vendor\Company\Model\ResourceModel\Slide\Grid\Collection">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">cartin24_respbannerslider</argument>
            <argument name="eventPrefix" xsi:type="string">slide_collection</argument>
            <argument name="eventObject" xsi:type="string">slide_collection</argument>
            <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Company\Model\ResourceModel\Slide</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>

</config>
```

But on upgrading the module(running the command) getting error as

> " [InvalidArgumentException]
>     There are no commands defined in the "setup" namespace.  "

Please help me with a solution.

I have displayed grid using ui component. Please see my app/code/Vendor/Company/view/adminhtml/ui_component/slide_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * @author Cartin24 Team
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2016 Cartin24 (http://www.cartin24.com)
 * @package Cartin24_Respbannerslider
 */
-->
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">

    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">slide_list.slidelist_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">slide_list.slidelist_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">slide_columns</item>  

    </argument>
    <dataSource name="slidelist_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">SlideGridDataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">slidelist_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <container name="listing_top">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/toolbar</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <bookmark name="bookmarks">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">slide_list</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </bookmark>
        <component name="columns_controls">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/controls/columns</item>
                    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">dataGridActions</item>
                    <item name="columnsData" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">slide_list.slide_list.slide_columns</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </component>    
<filters name="listing_filters">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="columnsProvider" xsi:type="string">slide_list.slide_list.slide_columns</item>
            <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">slide_list.slide_list.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.filters</item>
            </item>
            <item name="templates" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filters" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="select" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/ui-select</item>
                        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
            <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">slide_list.slide_list.slide_top.listing_filters</item>
                <item name="imports" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="string">slide_list.slide_list.product_columns.${ $.index }:visible</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</filters>

<!--
        <massaction name="listing_massaction">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">slide_list.slide_list.slide_columns.ids</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <action name="approve">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">approve</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Approve</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="marketz/product/massApprove"/>
                        <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Approve Product</item>
                            <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Are you sure you wan't to approve selected products?</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>                     
                </argument>
            </action> 
            <action name="deny">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">   
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="type" xsi:type="string">deny</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Deny</item>
                    <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="marketz/product/massDeny"/>
                    <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Deny items</item>
                        <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Are you sure you wan't to deny selected products?</item>
                    </item>
                </item>  
                </argument>
            </action>   

    </massaction> 
-->

    <paging name="listing_paging">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">slide_list.slide_list.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.paging</item>
                </item>
                <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">slide_list.slide_list.slide_columns.ids</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </paging>   
    </container>   

<columns name="slide_columns">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">slide_list.slide_list.slide_top.bookmarks</item>
                <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current</item>
            </item>
        </item>
            <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">slide_list.slide_list.slide_columns_editor</item>
                    <item name="target" xsi:type="string">startEdit</item>
                    <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="0" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
                        <item name="1" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">slide_list.slide_list.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                    <item name="root" xsi:type="string">columns.${ $.index }</item>
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.${ $.storageConfig.root }</item>
                </item>
            </item>
    </argument>
    <selectionsColumn name="ids">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </selectionsColumn>

        <column name="title">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                    <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">desc</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Title</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column> 
    </columns>
</listing>
```

Comment: On running the compile command,getting error as " [InvalidArgumentException]                                  
  There are no commands defined in the "setup:di" namespace.  "

Comment: Permissions are all correct and I have also created module.xml file and registered the module. When I remove the data source for one grid from di.xml file the other one is working fine.

Comment: Have you remove var folder from root?

Comment: Yes. I have removed it. But still getting the error on upgrading the module. Please help.

Comment: please show your command.

Comment: For compiling, I have run the command "sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade" .But getting error as http://i.prntscr.com/f441f1c5d3b14e8fb1c4d9928825ee55.png

Comment: refer this,https://mage2.pro/t/topic/552

Comment: I have updated the code. Please help me to find where I went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you declare `Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory` twice in your xml.

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="respbannerslider_data_source" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Company\Model\ResourceModel\Company\Grid\Collection</item>
        </argument>
   </arguments>
</type>

<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="slide_data_source" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Company\Model\ResourceModel\Slide\Grid\Collection</item>
        </argument>
   </arguments>
</type>
```

Use only one of them. Remove unnecessary one and give a try.